# Customized TimeZone in system versioned tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am learning how to use system versioned tables in SQL Server.  Everything is ok, but SQL Server uses the UTC timezone in the `sysstarttime` and `sysendtime` columns by default.

Is it possible change this behaviour? I would like to use the -5 GMT (my timezone) because when I need to auditing, I would need to know my local timezone when the rows were inserted, updated or deleted.

Comment: You can always query a table in your local timezone

Comment: No and you don't need to. UTC is a *better* option because it removes DST ambiguities. Storing what you assume is "local" time doesn't work *unless* you explicitly store the actual timezone name (not offset) in a separate column. What is -5 today may be -6 in the summer. And even if you assume your country has no DST now, it may have next year. Egypt changed its DST rules with just weeks of notice. The temporal columns are managed by the system so you don't have to worry about the actual local timezone. You can filter or convert the values to different timezones with `AT TIME ZONE`

Comment: Temporal tables aren't a shortcut for creating audit columns, they're much more. They actually show you the state of the entire database at a point in time. To do that there can't be any ambiguity in the database on what the actual time is, either now or in the future. That means the time columns can only be UTC or datetimeoffset. There's no need to know the original offset for temporal tables to work though, so it's UTC

Comment: While i agree with @PanagiotisKanavos re-utc times, sometimes one need to have the local time, because converting it later might not generate the exactly same time, depending on how well the rules are followed for historical timezone information. But nothing stops you from adding more columns which contains local date